# Algebraic manipulation with $\neq$ instead of $=$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Does ordinary algebraic manipulation work when $=$ is replaced with $\neq$?

For example, is the following a valid statement:

$p-1 \neq 6z\ \Rightarrow p \neq 6z + 1$

And if so, to what extent can this be expanded to other operations?

*Edit:* I guess formalising my question gave me the intuition to answer it (in the case of the simple example). We can suppose that $p - 1 \neq 6z$. But $p = 6z + 1 \Rightarrow p - 1 = 6z$, and so we have a contradiction. The *expansion to other operations* part of the question is still a mystery.

Comment: I'm not sure it's that mysterious. Alex.jordan's answer gives a very nice, clean condition for doing this:  the "operation" you're applying needs to be invertible (or at least one-to-one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's OK to do this *if* the action you take on both sides of the equation is invertible. In your example, adding $1$ is an invertible operation.

Adding a fixed number, subtracting a fixed number, multiplying by a nonzero number, and dividing by a nonzero number are all invertible actions you can take. So is raising to a power when that is an invertible action.

Comment: Except for even powers, no?

Comment: @Randall Oh, right :) I made an edit.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. If the operation is invertible, then we have a $\Leftrightarrow$ case and so the proof given in the edit to the question can be trivially extended. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  In general, be very careful when trying this.

In your stated example, it's okay.  Here's why.   If you were wrong and $p=6z+1$ then you are able to deduce $p-1=6z$, which you know to be false.  So, we're good here.

However, be VERY careful trying this with other more complicated things.  For example, the following is fallacious:
$$
x \neq 1 \Rightarrow x^2 \neq 1.
$$
This is wrong, for $x$ could have been $-1$.

In general, make sure that you can justify that this kind of move is right by looking at an equivalent formulation that uses (the much safer) equal signs.

Comment: Great counterexample! Really useful for getting me thinking along the right lines. I did upvote you, but I am accepting @alex.jordan's answer just because of the slightly nicer explanation.

Comment: @Awn Yep, I don't blame you.  Great question.

Comment: Another way to look at it: We know that $1^2=1$. If $x=1$, we can substitute to obtain $x^2=1$ and infer that $x=1 \implies x^2=1$. If $x \neq 1$, we cannot make any substitution.

Answer (score 2):

sometimes.

$p-1 = 6z \iff p = 6z+1$ so $p-1 \ne 6z \iff p \ne 6z+1$ so that is okay.

But

$x = 5 \not \iff x^2= 5^2$ so we *can't* say $x\ne 5 \implies x^2 \ne 25$.(Because $(-5)^2 = 25$.)

But we ***CAN*** so if $x^2 \ne 25 \implies x \ne 5$. (Because $5^2$ can't NOT equal $25$.)

Negation goes in the *REVERSE* order!

Think of this in terms of logic.

If $A \implies B$ then $\lnot B \implies \lnot A$.

So if $A = B \iff f(A) = f(B)$ (where $f(A)$ is something like $A+c$ and $m*D$) Then we can also to $f(A) = f(B) \implies A = B$ and $A\ne B \iff f(A) \ne f(B)$.

But if we only have $A=B \implies f(A)=f(B)$ but not $f(A)= f(B) \implies A=B$ (ex.  $f(a) = a^2$ or $f(a) = a^2$ then we can *Not* go $A \ne B \implies f(A) \ne f(B)$ (notice $x \ne 7 \not \implies |x| = |7|$ as $|-7| = |7|$ but $-7 \ne 7$.  But we *CAN* go $f(A) \ne f(B) \implies A \ne B$ (Notice!  $|x| \ne |7|$ then $x \ne 7$!!!)